# Virtual Populate in mongoose is not working?

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I am facing a problem in my virtual populate even though I have activated toJSON and toObject { virtuals : true} property i my Schema....

I have a tour Model like this in which I want ALL reviews

```
const tourSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a name'],
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
      maxlength: [40, 'A tour name must have less or equal then 40 characters'],
      minlength: [10, 'A tour name must have more or equal then 10 characters']
      // validate: [validator.isAlpha, 'Tour name must only contain characters']
    },
    slug: String,
    duration: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a duration']
    },
    maxGroupSize: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a group size']
    },
    difficulty: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a difficulty'],
      enum: {
        values: ['easy', 'medium', 'difficult'],
        message: 'Difficulty is either: easy, medium, difficult'
      }
    },
    ratingsAverage: {
      type: Number,
      default: 4.5,
      min: [1, 'Rating must be above 1.0'],
      max: [5, 'Rating must be below 5.0'],
      set: val => Math.round(val * 10) / 10 // 4.666666, 46.6666, 47, 4.7
    },
    ratingsQuantity: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a price']
    },
    guides: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      }
    ]
  }
  // ,
  // {
  //   toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  //   toObject: { virtuals: true }
  // }
);
tourSchema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true });
tourSchema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });

// Virtual Populate
tourSchema.virtual('reviews', {
  ref: 'Review',
  foreignField: 'tour',
  localField: '_id'
});

const Tour = mongoose.model('Tour', tourSchema);

module.exports = Tour;
```

and this is reviewsModel

```
const reviewsSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    review: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Review cannot be empty !']
    },
    rating: {
      type: Number,
      min: 1,
      max: 5
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    },
    tour: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Tour',
      required: [true, 'A Review must belong to a tour !']
    },
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: [true, 'A Review must belong to a User !']
    }
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
  }
);

const Review = mongoose.model('Review', reviewsSchema);
```

plz help me I have watched all question regarding to this issue on stackOverflow but they all said add toJSON and toObject and everything would be fine....But My project is still NOT fine...

Comment: Can you share the code where you are trying to use virtual populate? Additionally, can you describe what your expected behaviour is compared to what bahaviour you actually experience?

Comment: this is my code https://mega.nz/file/AnQx1KrK#tNW9jgJ8_VKgsxrkfq2fe3bvoswwZm3e1Fteg18yiOg

Comment: I appreciate you sharing the whole thing, but I am not going to debug your entire project (maybe someone else here will). Are you able to share a Minimal, Reproducible Example? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: is it not working when you use find multiple or one or both cases, would be much better if you shared here the actual code that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `tourController.js`, `getTour` function, populate the `reviews`:

`const tour = await Tour.findById(req.params.id).populate("reviews");`